# JaVA + MYSQL обновлять вне зависимости от изменений

Tags: java, mysql

Есть программа java которая обращается к БД каждую минуту.
код обращения

```
     String sql =  "INSERT INTO users(proclist, ip) VALUES ( ?, ?)  on 
  duplicate key update proclist = ?, online = 1";



            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, lp.toString());
            preparedStatement.setString(2, ownip);
            preparedStatement.setString(3, lp.toString());

            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Проблема в том, что если значения в столбце proclist такое же, как приходит от программы, обновление не происходит. Как заставить обновлять вне зависимости от совпадения?

Comment: И какой же констрейнт вызывает ODKU?

Comment: я его не использовал. для чего?

Comment: ODKU выполняется ***ТОЛЬКО*** в случае, когда данные при вставке приводят к нарушению ограничения уникальности. При отсутствии уникальных индексов ODKU не выполнится никогда.